# Windows Server 2012 - MSMQ - Journaling keeps disabling itself

Tags: windows, msmq

I'm trying to enabling journaling on my 2012 server - I have x2 queues on the host. One, I was able to enable this function and it has since stayed enabled. The other queue, I enable journaling on and it seems to be enabled, but after a few refreshes I go back into properties and it's turned itself off again.

The queue is used by a few applications - An IIS app and a custom service. Haven't tried to disable these as they are in constant use. Could this be the cause.

With the limit on the queue, what's the easiest way to check what the current storage quota is at?

Cheers all.

Comment: Public or Private queues?

Comment: Hi John,

Private queues

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Setting journaling will make changes to the corresponding text file in the C:\Windows\System32\msmq\storage\lqs folder. Find the weirdly named text file that matches your private queue. It will contain "Journal=01" if journaling enabled and "JournalQuota=12345" for the journal storage limit. If journaling is disabled after you switch it on, check the date/time stamp on the file to see if it has been updated. If no change in date then MSMQ isn't writing the changes to the file for some reason. If the date is changed but the journal settings are off then there must be some other process telling MSMQ to disable journaling (but that would mean a process monitoring journaling to ensure it isn't switched on). Try manually editing the file yourself in a text editor and see what happens; would need to restart the service to make MSMQ pick up the change.

Comment: Hi John,
Thanks for getting back to me. Funnily enough, I'm having the same issue again, Googled it and lord behold, I'm back here. So I've tried what you suggested above, found the file, changed the value for 0 to 1, in notepad++;  focus off notepad++, click back onto it, get a message saying "file has changed, would you like to reload"; reload the file, sure enough, journaling is back to 0 again. So something is changing it, what is the million dollar question.

Comment: Hi Jack :-)
I would use some system tool that allows you to see what processes have a file handle open on the text file you've updated. May find it's the custom service, for example.